# How to delete NW profile data on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, nwjs

"Your profile cannot be used because it's from a newer version of NW.js"

On Windows you delete the subfolder in `ApplicationData`, where is this on `Ubuntu 16.04`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in ~/.config/app_name. See http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Command%20Line%20Options/#-user-data-dir